# Simple prime number challenge haskell code gives incorrect answer

Tags: haskell

the code below tries to solve https://projecteuler.net/problem=87

```
import Math.NumberTheory.Primes.Sieve -- from package arithmoi

gen::[Integer]->Integer->[Integer]-- time complexity : n! , n = numberofprimes
gen pmlist limit=filter (\x->x<=limit) prelist
  where prelist=do
          let ls1=filter (\(x::Integer)->(x^2)<=limit) pmlist
          a<-ls1
          let ls2=filter (\(x::Integer)->(x^3)<=limit) ls1
          b<-ls2
          c<-filter (\(x::Integer)->(x^4)<=limit) ls2
  --  guard $ (b>=a)&&(c>=b)
          let res=(a^2+b^3+c^4)
          return res
main=do
  print "euler proj" -- other's answer:1097343 , my : 1139575

  print $ length  $ ep87 limit_1
--  print $  ep87

primesUnder i = takeWhile (\x->x<=i) primes -- library function
limit_1::Integer
limit_1=50000000
limit_2=1000000000
limit_3=10000000000

ep87 lmt =  gen (primesUnder lmt) lmt
```

The other's answer:1097343 , but this code snippet gives 1139575 , what could possibly be the culprit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method generates duplicates:

```
ghci> ep87 150
[28,93,47,112,145,33,98,52,117,150,49,114,68,133,73,138,92,145]
              ^^^                                          ^^^
```